# Geany: Is it possible to load basedir contents in Files tab when project is opened?

Tags: directory-structure, linux-mint, geany, geany-plugin

I've used Zend for development for years and am ready to switch to something new.  I've been checking out Geany 1.27 with the Projects and Files plugins loaded/activated.

Files under the Project tab are shown in list form (every single file, with no folders).  This is not good.

Is there a way to force Projects to use a directory tree layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the Tree Browser plugin.  This provides the functionality I was seeking.